# java garbage collection does a <(major collection:mark and sweep> every time it does a <minor collection:scavenge>

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have two applications (JVMs), each with the same settings and each using the default garbage collector.

They both have a min and max of 16 gbs of memory allocated.

One application acts the way i would expect.  When it minor collection(scavenges) it copies live objects to the survivor space.

The other application doesn't copy any objects to the survivor space.  Every time it does a minor collection(scavenge) it also does a major collection(mark and sweep).

Only reason i can think is that the survivor space is getting filled during the minor collection(scavenge).

Any ideas? or thoughts on how to diagnosis the behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I would try removing all the settings you have so that you have the absolute minimum and you are less likely to get a strange interaction between settings

Try just

```
-Xmx16g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

and monitor it using `jstat`

Comment: I used jstat on the current code base and it looks like the application makes a call to System.gc(), every-time it does a minor collection.  i'm not sure how it knows when a minor gc is occurring.

Comment: And you removed all the command line options you can?  I ask this as a a poor combination of options is the most likely cause.  The second most likely cause is an explicit call to System.gc() which is triggered after a minor collection.

Comment: I believe it is the 2nd one.  do you know how do get notified of a minor collection?

Comment: You can monitor the output of `jstat` or poll the GC information in JMX.  There is no event hook for when a GC is triggered.